# cp: cannot stat ... No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux

In a python script, I issue the command:

```
def copy_file(csv_file):    #csv_file = "wpa-01.csv"
    subprocess.call(["cp",csv_file,"tempfile.csv"])
```

I get the error:

```
cp: cannot stat 'wpa-01.csv' : No such file or directory
```

-tempfile.csv is a valid file, it is open
-I have tried adding quotes around wpa-01.csv, ie

```
subprocess.call(["cp","\"wpa-01.csv\"","tempfile.csv"])
```

-I have tried adding escape character in front of the '-'

-I have tried including the directory in front og the file name

-I am using gedit on a local Linux machine (so its not a dos2unix kind of solution), but the script is being ran on a remote Raspberry Pi

in every case I get the same error. I am at a loss for solutions. any suggestions?

***Here is the problem: "wpa-01.csv" is a 'live'/'dynamic' file. There is an active process that is updating that file in real time. I think that the file will have to be 'dead'/'static' in order to issue cp command? This is not ideal for my purposes. Is there a way to work around this like changing the mod or something? If not I suppose I can try to find an alternative solution.

Comment: also the file definitely exists, if I issue the command through the command line, it works

Comment: Why don't you just use `shutil.copy()`?

Comment: Does it work with other files than this one?

Comment: try ``import os; os.getcwd()`` and see that you're actually in the same directory the file is in.

Comment: What happens when you try './wpa-01.csv'?

Comment: this is the only "cp" command I do. "rm" works just fine. So does reading and writing. ./ gives the same result. And yes other files work fine. My best hunch is that it has to do with the '-'

Comment: '-' is a legal naming convention; guess, it should not matter. `subprocess.call(['cp','wpa-01.csv','tempfile.csv'])` works just fine in my comp

Comment: i just tried shutil.copyfile() and got same error, but thanks for suggestion- never heard of that module before

Comment: i just extracted the command from the script and it worked. So I guess the problem has to do with the fact that the string "wpa-01.csv" is actually getting passed as a parameter to the function that is issuing this command.

Comment: I think you need to add `shell=True` to the call

Comment: You'd be much better off using the standard library shutil.copyfile command. http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html

Comment: Adding quotes around the file will probably only worsen your problem, unless you use shell comprehension (shell=True), and then you'll have to provide all the arguments with the command as a string. I'm guessing that this is related to the file being written as you try to copy it. I have 2 suggestions: 1. Try using the full path for the file names. 2. try using cat instead `subprocess.call("cat /path/to/wpa-01.csv > /path/to/tempfile.csv", shell=True)`

Answer (score 1):

```
print "wpa-01.csv" in os.listdir(".") #make sure file really does exist
subprocess.call(["cp","\"wpa-01.csv\"","tempfile.csv"],shell=True)
```

My guess is you need to set shell=True so that it <s>uses your path to find cp</s> executes in your shell ... <s>if you don't use shell=True it wont use your path</s> ...

Unfortunately all it is  is a guess ...

Anyway, here is some supporting evidence:

```
>>> subprocess.call("copy tmp5.py tmp55.py")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 470, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 623, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\subprocess.py", line 833, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>>> subprocess.call("copy tmp5.py tmp55.py",shell=True)
        1 file(s) copied.
0
```

Comment: i'm always scared of shell=True but certainly worth a try given your results. I still got same error. thank you though

Comment: "if you dont use shell=True it wont use your path" -- actually, no.  Subprocess will always search your path, the `shell=True` argument does something else.

Comment: @JoranBeasley, when using `shell=True` you have to provide the program and its arguments as a string. With `shell=False` you have to provide the exec and variables as a list. Otherwise, python will try to execute a program called `copy\ tmp5.py\ tmp55.py` with no arguments, and that command does not exist.